# How to overwrite css with an additional class added?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

In md-autocomplete angular material how to overwrite the css as per the requirement without effecting the other implementation of same autocomplete.

```
<div flex="50" class="myclass" >

                    <md-autocomplete md-input-name="ownerAutocomplete"
                                     md-search-text=""
                                     md-selected-item=""
                                     md-selected-item-change=""
                                     md-items=""
                                     md-item-text="emp.name"
                                     md-floating-label="Owner"
                                     md-menu-class="custom-template"
                                     flex
                            style="margin-top:-2px">
                        <md-item-template>
                            <div class="item-title">
                                //my list of item
                            </div>
                        </md-item-template>
                    </md-autocomplete>
                </div>
```

I want to use this autocomplete search bar at two places, how can I write two diff css, when I write the below css and append myclass to the angular autocomplete css it also effects the other autocomplete bar where I have not used myclass as well.
For example I need border bottom to be displayed at one search bar and at other bar it should be border with 0px.

```
.myclass md-autocomplete.md-default-theme, md-autocomplete{
  background : transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
  background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
}
.myclass md-autocomplete input:not(.md-input)
{
    color: #444 !important;
    font-size:13.7px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "RionaSans-ExtraLight";
    opacity: 0.80;
}
.myclass md-autocomplete input[placeholder]
{
    color: #333 !important;
    font-family: "RionaSans-ExtraLight";
    opacity: 0.80;
    font-size:13.7px;
}
.myclass md-autocomplete *::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "RionaSans-ExtraLight";
    opacity: 0.80;
    font-size:13.7px;
}
.myclass md-autocomplete *:-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 4-18 */
    color: #333;
    font-family: "RionaSans-ExtraLight";
    opacity: 0.80;
    font-size:13.7px;
}
.myclass md-autocomplete *::-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 19+ */
    color: #333;
    font-family: "RionaSans-ExtraLight";
    opacity: 0.80;
    font-size:13.7px;
}
.myclass md-autocomplete *:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
    color: #333;
    font-family: "RionaSans-ExtraLight";
    opacity: 0.80;
    font-size:13.7px;
}
```

Comment: You may find reading this useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

`Specificity selector` is your answer.

For instance, if you are using a class called `.red` to give a `red` background to your element, CSS as below.

**For instance,**

```
.red{
    background:red;
}
```

Now, that element can have red class, but can also make other elements of the same class to get this red class.

To avoid that, use the top parent and keep on inheriting it till you come to the child red class. The best way is to start targetting it from the `id` selector, because that is unique and may not affect other elements.

**For instance,**

```
.#element1 div.otherclass div.otherclasses div.red{
    background:red;
}
```

Hope this helps.
You can read more [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)